# How to save files for a global 'CLI' npm node.js module

Tags: node.js, file, npm, command-line-interface, global

I’m designing an npm module (command line tool) to be used globally, and there's a heavy file that the user will need to choose among other big files to be downloaded, but once he choses and downloads it, it will be used always.

So I was wandering, where and how can I store this file so the module (the cli) can use it every other time is called?.

FYI: This is a module which is going to be used only in my company, is not intended to be offered  to the rest of the npm community. This module is intended to be used as a command line tool only, and not as a module dependency in any other one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. Add a `bin` key to your package.json. This is what will do your CLI
2. Install the package using npm -g
3. The package must be published to `npm` for installing it globally.

**bin key**

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

Add this to your package.json, so: `myapp` in the cli will run `cli.js` of your moudle.

```
{ "bin" : { "myapp" : "./cli.js" } }
```